# Excel formula to extract specific date and time from multiple lines of text in a cell

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

Can someone please help me with an excel formula or macro to extract the date and time in the 2nd last row? This text is part or a ticket dump export and I need date and time stamp of when it was first acknowledged. The names can vary and so can the lines of text, however, I would always need the date and time in the 2nd last line. Please help!

2021-08-01 19:17:21 - Kamatham Rakesh (Additional comments)
sample text

2021-08-01 19:04:48 - Shelley Black (Additional comments)
Sample Text

2021-08-01 19:04:31 - Kamatham Rakesh (Additional comments)
Sample text

2021-08-01 19:04:30 - Shelley Black (Additional comments)
Sample text

2021-08-01 19:04:05 - Shelley Black (Additional comments)
Sample text

2021-08-01 19:03:41 - Shelley Black (Additional comments)
Sample text

2021-08-01 19:03:25 - Shelley Black (Additional comments)
Hello

2021-08-01 19:03:17 - Kamatham Rakesh (Additional comments)
Hi shelly

2021-08-01 19:03:03 - Kamatham Rakesh (Additional comments)
Thank you for waiting. Sample text

2021-08-01 19:02:29 - Shelley Black (Additional comments)
sample text

Comment: Is this a 2nd account? It looks very similar to [https://stackoverflow.com/q/69303443/9758194](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69303443/9758194)

Comment: According to SO rules you should show us what you already tried [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - if all text is in a single column, this may work:

```
=INDEX( LEFT( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( A2, CHAR(10), "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ), 19 ),
        ROWS( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( A2, CHAR(10), "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) )-2 )
```

This assumes that the lines are separated by 2 carriage returns (i.e., `CHAR(10)`). It is delivering the text of the datetime.

[image: text version]

If you want to return the datetime value, it may be a lot easier to deploy this with a helper cell, but you can also do this:

```
=DATEVALUE( INDEX( LEFT( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( A2, CHAR(10), "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ), 19 ),
               ROWS( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( A2, CHAR(10), "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) )-2 ) )
+ TIMEVALUE( INDEX( LEFT( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( A2, CHAR(10), "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ), 19 ),
               ROWS( FILTERXML( "<main><sub>" & SUBSTITUTE( A2, CHAR(10), "</sub><sub>" ) & "</sub></main>", "//sub" ) )-2 ) )
```

Comment: Have a try with `=--LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-1]"),19)` and format the cell accordingly. It seems that if blank lines can excist (no matter how many) it would look like: `=--LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[node()][last()-1]"),19)`

Comment: That's really brilliant and quite reference-able!

Comment: @JvdV - thanks for the help. The formula is providing date and time for the last instance in the cell, however, I need the 2nd last date instance of the date and time extracted. Also, in some cells it is unable to compute at all and gives the #VALUE! error.

Comment: @vikramyadav, not for me tbh. At least not with the data provided as above in the answer given by Mark.

Comment: @VikramYadav - I also got a VALUE error on JvdV's first formula while the second one works perfectly. I think JvdV's first formula needs one mod to work. Try: `=--LEFT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-2]"),19)`. This fixed the problem for me. `[last()-1]` references the carriage return which will evaluate to VALUE, but `[last()-2]` will catch the line just above, which is what you want. Credit to JvdV. I did not know that you can coerce the string into a date (using --).

Comment: @markfitzpatrick - somehow it is not working with [last()-2]. Am I able to email the spreadsheet with sample data to you?

Comment: Hi @VikramYadav - it might make more sense to evaluate it on your machine. Here is a sample of the test string I used: `2021-08-01 19:03:17 - Kamatham Rakesh (Additional comments) Hi shelly

2021-08-01 19:03:03 - Kamatham Rakesh (Additional comments) Thank you for waiting. Sample text

2021-08-01 19:02:29 - Shelley Black (Additional comments) sample text`. If the `[node()][last()-1]` version from JvdV works, then you can use it instead.

Comment: Otherwise, you can try to diagnose the problem by simply putting this formula in a cell and seeing that it outputs: `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-2]")`. Then try variations such as `[last()-0]` and `[last()-1]`... This part of his formula is just pulling out each line of the string. The LEFT() is just stripping out the datetime and the -- coerces that into an actual datetime. I suspect that the issue you have is that the lines of your text are not separated by CHAR(10) carriage return/linefeeds.

Comment: I just realized that in the sample text I gave you, the comments on will not support linefeeds. Try putting this into a cell as your test data: `=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),1,{"2021-08-01 19:03:03 - Kamatham Rakesh (Additional comments) Thank you for waiting. Sample text";0;"2021-08-01 19:02:29 - Shelley Black (Additional comments) sample text";0;"2021-08-01 19:03:17 - Kamatham Rakesh (Additional comments) Hi shelly

2021-08-01 19:03:03 - Kamatham Rakesh (Additional comments) Thank you for waiting. Sample text

2021-08-01 19:02:29 - Shelley Black (Additional comments) sample text"})`.

Comment: If you want to see which ASCII text is being used to separate your lines, put this formula into a cell somewhere on your worksheet and it will spill out all of the character codes, side by side, so that you can see them: `=CHOOSE({1;2},MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1),CODE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1)),1)))`. See if it is really 10.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick - thanks heaps - using [last()-6] worked for me like a charm!!

=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(10),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()-6]")

Comment: Great news!!  Cheers @VikramYadav.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

```
=DATEVALUE( LEFT( INDEX( A:A, LARGE(IF( ISTEXT(A:A), ROW(A:A) ),2) ), 19) )
+ TIMEVALUE( LEFT( INDEX( A:A, LARGE(IF( ISTEXT(A:A), ROW(A:A) ),2) ), 19) )
```

This assumes the data are laid out in Column A of some arbitrary length:
[image: result]

This might take a lot of time to calc if your data are really long. There could be more calc-efficient ways if you knew exactly how many rows are in the data set. Unfortunately, the IF has to be repeated because the TIMEVALUE and DATEVALUE are computed separately and in Excel 2016, you don't have access to LET or FILTER which would speed things up a bit.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Thanks for your response. The data is not in rows, but is from just one cell, I have many rows of similar data with variable lengths.

Comment: @VikramYadav - ah ok. Excel 2016 is challenging. Will think about that...